# Subdivision surface not working properly

Tags: rendering

I don't know if this is a bug or something else but when I use Subdivision surface my "View" tab is controlling both "View" and "Render". It's like I don't need "Render" option. By setting "Render" value to 4 and my "View" value is 1-2 on rendered model it will show me the value of "View" and not my "Render" value. If I change "View" value on 4 and "Render" value on "what ever number" it will show me the value of "View". I didn't try other modifiers. Is this something that is fixable or do I have to change my "View" to render stuff on the value I want?

Comment: Are you saying, when you make a final render, using Cycles or Blender Internal, you only see the 'View' subdiv level?.. (Rendering in the viewport is still considered 'View')

Comment: It happens when I do "quick" render to see what needs to be fixed. Not a final render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, the *Render* value is for the definitive render, the one you get when you press the *Render* button in the *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Render*, it is not for the *Rendered* display option you have on the dropdown menu of the horizontal menu bar of the 3D View, this one takes the *View* value into account. It's a bit confusing, yes.

Also, in *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Sampling* > *Samples*, you choose the final *Render* sampling value and the 3D view *Preview* sampling value. You generally don't work your 3D view with a value as high as the *Render* value because it would take too much time. But in Blender 2.8 you'll have Eevee which is quite fast.

Comment: So "Render" value is only for final render and not for "quick" renders to see what needs to be fixed?

Comment: exactly, you have the final Render, and you have the quick render which is the Rendered mode, which is only a preview. Also, in Properties panel > Render > Sampling > Samples, you choose the final Render sampling value and the 3D view Preview sampling value. You generally don't work your 3D view with a value as high as the Render value because it would take too much time. But in Blender 2.8 you'll have Eevee which is quite fast. I havent't tried it already so I can't tell how to set.

Comment: This is why it's called "Rendered" viewport shading, to avoid confusion with an actual "render". Not enough IMO, they could label it "preview render". x)